# swap keys and values in a map

Tags: clojure

Is there a function to swap the key and value of a given map. So given a map, I want the keys to become values, and values the keys.

```
(swap {:a 2 b 4}) => {2 :a 4 :b}
```

One way to do it is

```
(zipmap (vals my-map) (keys my-map))
```

However wondering if clojure provides a utility fn for this?

Comment: This is not always possible: `{:a 1 :b 1}`. If you want to preserve information then *sets* of keys should become values: `{1 #{:a :b}}`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the purpose of `map-invert` in `clojure.set`:

```
user=> (clojure.set/map-invert {:a 2 :b 4})
{4 :b, 2 :a}
```

Comment: Any reason why it is in clojure.set instead of clojure.core ? I mean any gotchas I need to be aware of ?

Comment: Historical development/relative importance, perhaps. See `(source clojure.set/map-invert)` -- no surprises.

Comment: It does share the set's behavior of not storing duplicates - only the last of any given val becomes a key (with its accompanying key as value)

Comment: I had a similar problem but the values could represent multiple keys.

I found that the best solution was (on small maps of about 20 keys. - surprisingly better than using reduce):
`(->> (group-by second {:a 1 :b 2 :c 1 :d 3 :e 2 :f 1})
           (map (fn [[k v]] [k (set (map first v))]))
           (into {}))`

Answer (score 7):

For anyone reading this at a later date I think the following should be helpful.

A small library is available here https://clojars.org/beoliver/map-inversions

Inverting a map may return a relation. If the map is injective (one-to-one) then the inverse will also be one-to-one. If the map (as if often the case) is many-to-one then you should use a set or vector.

#Values treated as atomic
##one-to-one
the values of the map are unique

```
(defn invert-one-to-one
  "returns a one-to-one mapping"
  [m]
  (persistent! (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (assoc! m v k)) (transient {}) m)))

(def one-to-one {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})

> (invert-one-to-one one-to-one)
{1 :a 2 :b 3 :c}
```

##many-to-one
The values of the map are **not** unique. This is very common - and it is safest to assume that your maps are of this form... so `(def invert invert-many-to-one)`

```
(defn invert-many-to-one
  "returns a one-to-many mapping"
  ([m] (invert-many-to-one #{} m))
  ([to m]
   (persistent!
    (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
              (assoc! m v (conj (get m v to) k)))
            (transient {}) m))))

(def many-to-one {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2})

> (invert-many-to-one many-to-one)
{1 #{:b :a}, 2 #{:c}} ; as expected

> (invert-many-to-one [] many-to-one)
{1 [:b :a], 2 [:c]} ; we can also use vectors

> (invert-one-to-one many-to-one) ; what happens when we use the 'wrong' function?
{1 :b, 2 :c} ; we have lost information
```

#Values treated as collections
##one-to-many
values are sets/collections but their intersections are always empty.
(No element occurs in two different sets)

```
(defn invert-one-to-many
  "returns a many-to-one mapping"
  [m]
  (persistent!
   (reduce (fn [m [k vs]] (reduce (fn [m v] (assoc! m v k)) m vs))
           (transient {}) m)))

(def one-to-many (invert-many-to-one many-to-one))
> one-to-many
{1 #{:b :a}, 2 #{:c}}

> (invert-one-to-many one-to-many)
{:b 1, :a 1, :c 2} ; notice that we don't need to return sets as vals
```

##many-to-many
values are sets/collections and there exists at least two values whose intersection is not empty. If your values are collections then it is best to assume that they fall into this category.

```
(defn invert-many-to-many
  "returns a many-to-many mapping"
  ([m] (invert-many-to-many #{} m))
  ([to m]
   (persistent!
    (reduce (fn [m [k vs]]
              (reduce (fn [m v] (assoc! m v (conj (get m v to) k))) m vs))
            (transient {}) m))))

(def many-to-many {:a #{1 2} :b #{1 3} :c #{3 4}})

> (invert-many-to-many many-to-many)
{1 #{:b :a}, 2 #{:a}, 3 #{:c :b}, 4 #{:c}}

;; notice that there are no duplicates when we use a vector
;; this is because each key appears only once
> (invert-many-to-many [] many-to-many)
{1 [:a :b], 2 [:a], 3 [:b :c], 4 [:c]}

> (invert-many-to-one many-to-many)
{#{1 2} #{:a}, #{1 3} #{:b}, #{4 3} #{:c}}

> (invert-one-to-many many-to-many)
{1 :b, 2 :a, 3 :c, 4 :c}

> (invert-one-to-one many-to-many)
{#{1 2} :a, #{1 3} :b, #{4 3} :c} ; this would be missing information if we had another key :d mapping to say #{1 2}
```

You could also use `invert-many-to-many` on the `one-to-many` example.

Answer (score 6):

There's a function [`reverse-map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.datalog.util/reverse-map) in clojure.contrib.datalog.util, it's implemented as:

```
(defn reverse-map
  "Reverse the keys/values of a map"
  [m]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [v k]) m)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that may fit the problem using reduce:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 (second %2) (first %2)) {} {:a 2 :b 4})
```

Here in a function

```
(defn invert [map]
  (reduce #(assoc %1 (second %2) (first %2)) {} map))
```

Calling

```
(invert {:a 2 b: 4})
```

Then there is the `reduce-kv` (cleaner in my opinion)

```
(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %3 %2) {} {:a 2 :b 4})
```