# Clojure get map key by value

Tags: clojure

I'm a new clojure programmer.

Given...

```
{:foo "bar"}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the name of the key with a value "bar"?

I've looked through the map docs and can see a way to retrieve key and value or just value but not just the key.  Help appreciated!

Comment: Sure, but it usually means your data structure is upside down.

Comment: So... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595986/swap-keys-and-values-in-a-map ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're doing (perhaps you can instead change the code which creates the map, or you need both directions), but my hunch would be: Yes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There can be multiple key/value pairs with value "bar". The values are not hashed for lookup, contrarily to their keys. Depending on what you want to achieve, you can look up the key with a linear algorithm like:

```
(def hm {:foo "bar"})
(keep #(when (= (val %) "bar")
          (key %)) hm)
```

Or

```
(filter (comp #{"bar"} hm) (keys hm))
```

Or

```
(reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
             (if (= v "bar")
               (conj acc k)
               acc))
           #{} hm)
```

which will return a seq of keys. If you know that your vals are distinct from each other, you can also create a reverse-lookup hash-map with

```
(clojure.set/map-invert hm)
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing if hm is like {1 ["bar" "choco"]}? The idea being to get 1 where the first element if the value list is "bar" ?

Comment: @smaug This should be obvious from the code. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question?

Answer (score 6):

```
user> (->> {:a "bar" :b "foo" :c "bar" :d "baz"} ; initial map
           (group-by val)   ; sorted into a new map based on value of each key
           (#(get % "bar")) ; extract the entries that had value "bar"
           (map key))     ; get the keys that had value bar
(:a :c)
```

Answer (score 2):

As in many other cases you can use for:

```
(def hm {:foo "bar"})
(for [[k v] hm :when (= v "bar")] k)
```

And with "some" you can return the first matching item instead of a list (as probably the original question implied):

```
(some (fn [[k v]] (if (= v "bar") k)) hm)
```