# Clojure: How to retrieve hash from vector by value

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to retrieve an entire hash from a vector of hashes based on whether or not it has a specific value in a field.

```
(def foo {:a 1, :b 2})
(def bar {:a 3, :b 4})
(def baz [foo bar])
```

In `baz`, I want to return the entire hash where `:a 3` so the result will be `{:a 3, :b 4}`.  I have tried `get` `get-in` and `find` but those rely on keys and do not return the entire hash.  I've also tried some suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176372/clojure-get-map-key-by-value) but they don't return the hash either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter to the rescue!

```
hello.core> (def foo {:a 1, :b 2})
#'hello.core/foo
hello.core> (def bar {:a 3, :b 4})
#'hello.core/bar
hello.core> (def baz [foo bar])
#'hello.core/baz

hello.core> (filter #(= (:a %) 3) baz)
({:a 3, :b 4})
```

`#(= (:a %) 3)` is a short form for creating an anonymous that takes one argument, named `%`, in which it will look up the key `:a` and return true if that matches the value 3. Any entry in the vector `baz` which passes this test will make it into the output.

PS: a note on pronunciation: that data structure is typically called a "map" because it maps one key to one value. This is terribly confusing because there is also a function named `map` which changes every member of a sequence by a function.

Comment: `(filter (comp #{3} :a) baz)`?

Answer (score 2):

`filter` definitely does the job as Arthur mentioned. Just for the sake of completeness these are 2 other solutions which differ in 2 aspects from `filter`:

```
(some #(when (= 3 (:a %)) %) baz)
(first (drop-while #(not= 3 (:a %)) baz))
```

1. these will stop further searching through your whole collection as soon as they have found the first element in the collection which fits your requirements (hence less resource) and
2. because of that, in contrary to filter they give you only the first fitting element and not all the elements in the collection which pass your 
   requirements (in case you have multiple repeated elements in your collection).